# Laravel 5.2 - How to get the SQL generated by your seeds

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-seeding

I have some seeds and I simply want to see the SQL they generate. With migrations I would simply do `--pretend` but this isn't an option for `db:seed`.

I also realize that I can see all the SQL statements that I run by using `DB::getQueryLog()` etc. However, I don't want to actually execute the SQL.

Any ideas on how to generate the SQL your seed files would produce without actually running the sql?

Sample insert from one of my seeders:

```
    DB::table('aca_reporting_1094_fields')->insert([
        [
            'field_name'    => 'business_name',
            'value'         => 'Sesame St R Us',
            'record_status' => 1,
            'created_at'    => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'updated_at'    => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        ],
    ]);
```

I realize I am probably missing something simple here and thanks for the helpful comments. I will look into extending the seed command and see if I do it successfully I will leave the answer (unless someone beats me to it).

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/debugging-queries-in-laravel

Comment: If you are using query builder, you can just call the `toSql()` method. A better option might be to extend the seed command, and add an option for dry-run. Based on that option, you can execute the command or print the SQL.

Comment: In my experience there is little value in asking people why they have downvoted, since once they have done so they will have long gone. However, if it is important to you, please add it to the comments, so the post can remain focussed on the problem.